# Cannot convert DateTime to Hours

Tags: php, wordpress

I' am trying to covert date time to hours so that today's date and time matches with the database date and time.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");
today = date('Y-m-d H:i'); // Returns 2014-05-01 11:01

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i', '2014-05-02 11:05');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // Returns 2014-05-02 11:05
```

What am I doing wrong in this code that its returning `2014-05-02 11:05` whereas it should return `2014-05-01 23:05`

Answer (score 0):

You saved `2014-05-02 11:05` in Fiji timezone to `$date`. Afterwards you display the date in Fiji timezone, so of course no change is made.

I don't really understand your question but from the code you provide I guess that what you probably want to do is the following:

```
$tzFiji = new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Fiji');
$tzBerlin = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$tzCurrent = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i', '2014-05-02 11:05', $tzFiji);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'); # date in Fiji's timezone
$date->setTimezone($tzBerlin);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'); # date in Berlin's timezone
$date->setTimezone($tzCurrent);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'); # date in php's currently set timezone
```